# Electron IPC excessive messages

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, electron, dom-events

I am experimenting on the Electron (atom shell) platform for building a desktop app, currently on mac os x.

I am trying its IPC (inter processes communication) module for sending and receiving sync and async messages in between two main electron processes, main and the renderer processes.

However with async messages I get more than expected replies for messages ı have sent from the renderer process to main process, where they are replied. I know this form the console output the replies from the main process should produce.

For each of 2 components of DOM, I send 1 single message to main process, and it responds with a reply which logs to console. But for 2 components(react components) I get 4 console log lines and for 3 it is 9, and for 4 it is 16 console log messages lines.

What is going on here? What am I missing about async messages and replies with IPC? no problem with sync messages and replies.

main.js (main process code):

```
var app = require('app');  // Module to control application life.
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');  // Module to create native browser window.
var ipc = require('ipc');

// Report crashes to our server.
require('crash-reporter').start();

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is GCed.
var mainAppWindow = null;
var bookWindow = null;

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  app.quit();
});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainAppWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1200, height: 900, 'title-bar-style': 'hidden'});

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainAppWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  mainAppWindow.openDevTools();
  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainAppWindow.on('closed', function() {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainAppWindow = null;
    app.quit();
  });

  ipc.on('asynchronous-message', function(event, arg) {
    console.log(arg);  // prints "ping"
    event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong');
  });


  // listen for the messages from renderer process to close the mainwindow and open a readerwindow
  ipc.on('synchronous-message', function(event, arg) {
    console.log(arg);  // prints "ping"
    event.returnValue = 'pong';
  });
  // when all of the book reader windows are closed open the mainAppWindow
  // in main process listen for all bookreaderwindows are closed
  // and in each, checking an array of them formed when they are each created.
});
```

index.js (renderer process code):

```
/*
-mainApp
  -Controls
  -Books
    -Book
*/
var ipc = require('ipc');

var Book = React.createClass({
  switchToBookReader: function() {
    // close mainAppWindow, and open bookreader window.
    // send message to main process 'close window'.
    // listen in main process for this.
    // callback for this in main process is to close the main window and open a readerwindow
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    ipc.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping');
    ipc.on('asynchronous-reply', function(arg) {
      console.log(arg); // prints "pong"
    });
    console.log(ipc.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')); // prints "pong"
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div onDoubleClick={this.switchToBookReader()} >
        {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Books = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    // create Book nodes here.
    var bookNodes = [];
    bookNodes.push(<Book name="book1"/>);
    bookNodes.push(<Book name="book2"/>);


    return (
      <div>
        {bookNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Controls = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        Controls
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var mainApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Controls />
        <Books />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<mainApp />, document.body);
```

Comment: Wait! Is the answer the 2 listening `<Book>` components in the renderer process captures the async 2 replies from the main process, and each of the 2 components console logs for each of these 2 processes? 2 messages sent to main and it fired 2 replies, 2 components in renderer listens and each captures each and each 2 logs 2 console logs, adds up to 4, the square of the number of the listening components.

Comment: Anybody have a solution to this problem..

Answer (score 3):

Every listener creates a unique ID which is returned when creating the listener. Based on that, removing listener could be done like this:

```
ipcRenderer.once(channel, listener);
```

Adds a one time listener function for the event. This listener is invoked only the next time a message is sent to channel, after which it is removed.

visit https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/#ipcrendereroncechannel-listener

got solution here and working.